# Conversion of complex numbers to standard form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

$$(1/\sqrt{2} - i/\sqrt{2})^8$$
Im not sure where to begin here, should i just expand it out completely and then simplify?

$$1/i^{2013}$$
For this one im guessing because $2012$ is basically the same as $i^0$ then this would be the same as $i^1$ and be just $1/i$ 
does that count as standard form?

$$(\log 4 + 11i\pi)/4 $$
not really sure what to do here at all with the pi or log?

$$3^{0.5-(i\pi/6\log 3)}$$
again i'm really not sure how to approach this one!

Comment: For the first one, they're expecting you to use de Moivre's theorem.

The third one just looks like "divide by 4", which is hopefully not a problem by now.

Is everything supposed to be in the power for the fourth one?

Comment: Combining independent problems into one Question is discouraged.  It becomes hard to parse out what point you've gotten to with each part, and what specific instruction is required to get you over a difficulty.

Comment: The main idea is to re-write the base using polar coordinates, and distribute the exponent, then to re-convert back it into Cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the exponential function:
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^8 = \big(\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4)\big)^8 = \exp(i\pi/4)^8=\exp(2\pi i)=1
\end{equation}